# Casting syntax practice

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

I have a code which goes like :

```
int main(void)
{
    char mychar = 'd';
    int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr)) ;

    *ptr = (char) 'c' ; // *ptr = (char*) 'c'; Gives the exact same result

    printf("%c\n",*ptr);
    memset(ptr,mychar,sizeof(*ptr));
    printf("%c\n",*ptr);
    free(ptr);
    printf("%c\n",*ptr);
    return 0 ;
}
```

The code gives the same result for pointer style cast and datatype cast.
Which among the two styles should be used or is considered a good practice and why ?

```
*ptr = (char) 'c' ; 
*ptr = (char*) 'c';
```

Comment: Tried turning on your compiler warnings?

Comment: I think none of them is good, since you are assigning a char to an int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither.

Both `*ptr` and `'c'` are of type `int`. No cast is necessary.

(Yes, character constants in C are of type `int`, not `char`. This is counterintuitive, but there are historical reasons for it. Note that C++ character constants are of type `char`.)

The cast in `*ptr = (char) 'c';` is relatively harmless; it converts the `int` value of `'c'` to `char`, and the result is implicitly converted back to `int`.  Since `c` is guaranteed to be representable as a `char`, it's not going to cause an error.

In `*ptr = (char*) 'c';`, your compiler *should* give you an error message. You're converting a constant `int` value to a pointer, and then assigning that pointer value to an `int` without a cast. This is a "constraint violation", which means that a conforming compiler *must* diagnose it. If yours doesn't, find out how to make it do so.

If the assignment gets past the compiler, it *might* do what you want. Conversions between integer types and pointer types typically just reinterpret the bits that name up the representation, so converting an `int` to a `char*` and back to an `int` is likely to give you the original `int` value. But it's not guaranteed.

Casts are usually unnecessary even between different arithmetic types. For example, if you had written:

```
char ch = 'c';
int i;
i = ch;
```

In this case, the right side of the assignment really is of type `char`, because it's the name of an object of that type, not a character constant. The assignment **implicitly** converts the value of `ch` from type `char` to type `int`. You *could* write:

```
i = (int)ch;
```

instead, but that just specifies the same conversion that would have been done without the cast. And it's error-prone; it introduces the opportunity to get the type wrong, as opposed to letting the compiler handle it for you.

Casts in general should be viewed with suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

Both are bad.

`'c'` is actually an `int`. So you don't have to cast. You can directly assign it:

```
*ptr = 'c';
```

Comment: I'd go with Heisenbug: Both the OP's casts are equally bad, since neither cast is actually casting to the left-hand-side type.